# Ruby - Iterate over array and create a three column, x rows table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, view

In a view, I get an array of objects.  I want to have a three column table that will be filled with an attribute of those objects.  So, if my list has 5 objects, my table will have two rows: the first row will contain three cells, and the second row 2 cells.

How do I iterate over that list in order to accomplish this?

Comment: This is one big long non-sequitur.  How do you get from 5 objects to only two rows?

Comment: 5 objects and I have 3 objects per row (3 columns)

Comment: It would be better to post what you have attempted so far and tell us where you're stuck.  Here is a hint..you will want to start a new row when n % 3 is 0.  'n' being your current position in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use tables and just iterate over your array you could use [each_slice](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) and go over the returned arrays, like `your_array.each_slice(3)`

But you could also *not* use tables, use some divs for example, and iterate over your big (5 objects) array and style the divs so that they fit 3 in a row.